# Fortify fix for XML External Entity Injection

Tags: java, fortify, xxe

When I do scan using fortify tool, I got some issues under "XML External Entity Injection".

```
TransformerFactory trfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

This is the place where it is showing error. I have given the below fix as suggested by fortify

```
trfactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false); 
trfactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
```

but still the issues are not fixed. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Please share any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

```
TransformerFactory trfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
trfactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
trfactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
trfactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

This would be sufficient.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks ): .
Before this, I tried the solution suggested by Fortify and that didn't worked.

Comment: @AlessandroIudicone Link to the solution suggested by Fortify please!

Answer (score 1):

**Sometime it will not work if java version is not compatible.**

```
if (javaVersion > 1.6) {
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
      }
else {
        if (javaVersion > 1.5) {
          dbf.setFeature("http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#external-general-entities", false);
          dbf.setFeature("http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#external-parameter-entities", false);
        }
else {
          dbf.setFeature("http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html#external-general-entities", false);
          dbf.setFeature("http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html#external-parameter-entities", false);
        }
 }
```

> It worked for me :-)

Comment: is it working ? do we need to fix for Transformer or Document Builder Factory As  part of security fortify issue??

Comment: yes it is working.The providing fixes are wrt the place where it is showing error in fortify tool, in my case I fix it for Document Builder Factory @lax

Comment: encode for sql from esapi might be the correct fix for this issue

Answer (score 0):

I tried with "Xalan" implementation class instead of TransformerFactory.newInstance().It worked for me and fortify issue got fixed

```
        TransformerFactoryImpl transformerFactoryImpl = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
    TransformerFactoryImpl transformerFactoryImpl = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer();
    transformer.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

Comment: is it working ? do we need to fix for Transformer or Document Builder Factory As  part of security fortify issue??

Answer (score 0):

Add this line. It worked for me.

```java
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
```

Comment: this will throw an exception instead of processing a request whenever you include doctype